# ssis package with proxy account in sql job

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, jobs

I made an SSIS package that exports data from Microsoft SQL Server and imports it into a .csv and mysql file. I start to use **proxy account** and it **work**, but only when **user is logged**. ***How make it works when user is logged off*** !? Thank you in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: SSIS is part of SQL Server, not MySQL. You're not connecting to your SQL Server instance here, so you won't be able to start it. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different RDBMS.

Comment: SSIS package good work in VS, and sql job with this package good work if user logged on. But, if user off then job fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Firstly, created System DSN.
[link for this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14401/How-to-Schedule-and-Run-a-SSIS-package-DTS-Job-in)

> Does any connection manager in the package use ODBC DSN? If any ODBC
>   DSN is used, please make sure the DSN type is System DSN rather than
>   User DSN. The user DSN may not be accessible when the user that create
>   the DSN logs off.

Secondly, create new proxy and give him credentials
[link for this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cbf9942c-7a1d-4c20-84d5-9326e1ae0933/ssis-package-only-runs-when-user-is-logged?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

```
Use master
CREATE CREDENTIAL [MyCredential] WITH IDENTITY = 'yourdomain\myWindowAccount', secret = 'WindowLoginPassword'
Use msdb
Sp_add_proxy @proxy_name='MyProxy', @credential_name='MyCredential'
Sp_grant_login_to_proxy @login_name=' devlogin', @proxy_name='MyProxy'
Sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name='MyProxy', @subsystem_name='SSIS'
```